# Int ID jumps numbers when an entry is deleted an added in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

1. Actually, i have written a code to delete and add new user in MySQL table and both are working properly.
2. And the id is the primary key and auto incremental.
3. The issue is that suppose the last entry has an id '9', when i delete that entry and add a new one, the new entry has an id '10' instead of '9'.

Comment: it is because the auto-increment counter has moved to 10. If you are worried about gaps. You will have to reset the counter everytime. But in real-life applications, it should not be that much of a concern as long as the value is unique (which is covered by PK constraint already)

Comment: If you are worried about gaps, reeducate yourself until you are no longer worried about gaps.

Comment: If you inserted 5 users, assigned ids 1-5, then deleted user 3 and created another user, would you also expect the new user to re-use id 3? Why would you expect that? If not, why would you expect re-use for last id if not for other ids? --- As already mentioned by others, learn what "auto increment" means.

Answer (score 3):

As per [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [15.6.1.5 AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) once an `auto_increment` value is generated it's not reused. When deleting rows from the table you will observe gaps in the `auto_increment` number sequence.

Even if there is a rollback on the inserting transaction:

> if a transaction that generated auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled back. Such lost values are not reused. Thus, there may be gaps in the values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.